# Decrease the workload used by python monitor task for the cpu

Tags: python, request, cpu, monitor

I am working on a monitor with python to detect new products on websites. I would like to run multiple instances to increase the chance of detecting something.

My goal is to decrease the workload for the CPU to be able to run more instances. A function like `time.sleep` is not a real option since it decreases the likelihood to detect a product.

I have already brought the script down to a minimum. Are there any other options to minimize the workload?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without more details on how the monitor works and what is consuming the CPU. I would suggest you use a profiling tool (There is one in PyCharm for example) that will monitor your function calls and the time they took. This way you can focus on what takes too long or consumes to much resources and improve those parts accordingly.

Comment: Iam using request and beatifulsoup to get the information from the website and if the product is new a discord webhook will send the link and the productname.

Comment: If it's using requests I would suggest trying to combine different requests instead of a different request per product. Check if there is an API to query a number of products for example instead of querying one at a time. Using requests means that you are waiting for some response each time, which is basically wasting some time and CPU while doing nothing until the response arrives